# Create scope for current state using if/then in Ruby / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, scope

I'm trying to figure out how to create a scope for 'late' jobs.

A 'late' job will be one where the state is :in_progress where the :due date is older than today.

(I'm not using any state gems and have Postgres as the database).

This is what I have going so far. I'm fairly new to if then statements and have only created basic scopes to this point. Any thoughts on how to go about this in my model?

# states

```
  STATES = %w[bids in_progress complete canceled]
  delegate :bids?, :in_progress?, :complete?, :canceled?, to: :current_state

  def current_state
    (events.last.try(:state) || STATES.first).inquiry
  end
```

# scope

```
  def self.late
    if @current_state_jobs == :in_progress?
      where('due < ?', Time.now) 
    else
      nil 
    end
  end
```

Can I use the first current_state scope in the late scope? I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your setup, but I can certainly help steer you in the right direction.

I don't believe your delegate statement will work because as far as I know it needs to set the `:on` option to an object of some sort and not a method. In your case, what I think you need to delegate to is `state.inquiry`. There's probably a way to do that, but I'm afraid I don't know how.

Here is a quick discussion on delegates that seemed pretty helpful to me:

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/

With that in mind, these delegate methods are still instance methods, and a scope needs class methods.

I'm not sure what `@current_state_jobs` is supposed to be, but that's an instance variable and you're in a class function so I don't think it works. I think what you're really looking for is simply `where(state: "in_progress")`.

Next you want to do a query on the date which is actually kind of tricky. If you're not careful, `Time.now` sort of gets binded when the module is first loaded. To prevent that, you need to use a `lambda` function to ensure the time is based on when the function is called.

Also, you said in the description that you want the method to include anything that is "older than today", but what your query is doing is anything "older than right now".

To sum it all up I think you need something like this:

```
scope :late, lambda { where("state=? and due < ?", "in_progress", Date.today) }
```

If it were me, I'd probably break it into two different scopes like `in_progress` and `overdue` then have `:late` just be `in_progress.overdue`, but if you're not going to use either of those other two scopes then it's unnecessary.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Geoff - scoping with the lambda function worked exceptionally well. I need to start thinking about the lambda way. Wasen't sure what I was thinking trying to use instane variable in there since its already calling on self. Pretty new to this. 

The delegate statement works for the states - for now.

Cheers

Comment: I suppose the function is returning an object, so maybe that's why it works. Also, I think I understand your problem better too. You may have figured it out already, but I think you may need a `joins(:events)` before the `where` above.